# Javascript output is acting wierd

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a

```
        <p id="err_output"></p>
```

on my page, it is linked to this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#username").on('keyup',check_username_existence);
 });
```

The function is such :

```
function check_username_existence(){
    $.ajax({ url: './php/user_name_availability.php',
         data: { username : $('#username').val() },
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(output);
                $('#err_output').html(json.response.exist);

                if(json.response.exist == 'true'){
                //  $('#err_output').html('Exists');
                }
         }
    });
};
```

the values for json response are:

```
{ "response" : { "exist" : true   } }
{ "response" : { "exist" : false  } }
```

Problem is that it only outputs when exist is true.

If I put

```
 $('#err_output').html( output + json.response.exist);
```

on the other hand it would output false values as well.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if(json.response.exist == 'true'){
```

Is comparing to the string `"true"`, but you have a boolean `true` stored, it should work with:

```
if (json.response.exist) {
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I got spoiled with php's autocasting.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the quotes and use the identity operator (===). It will give you the result you expect

```
if(json.response.exist === true){
```

Weak comparisons can give you strange results. Here's an example of why it's evaluating the way it is in your code.

```
bool = "false";
if(bool){
  // bool evaluates to true because it is defined as a string
}

bool = 'true';
if(bool == true){
  // doesn't execute. comparing string to boolean yields false
}
```